# Pass content of Silverlight 5 DataGrid HyperlinkButton into a function

Tags: silverlight, button, methods, parameters, hyperlink

Ok ... I did do some looking and maybe I did not have the correct keywords so I apologize in advance if this has been asked in this forum before.

I am trying to pass the text value of a valid hyperlink into a method in the .cs code behind. I can handle everything else fine, just need to get the correct format for passing the TranId value into the click method "linkGetPayload_Click". I think I am missing something with the binding. Here is the XAML:

```
<HyperlinkButton Content="{Binding TranId}" 
                 Click="lnkGetPayload_Click({Binding TranId})" />
```

Comment: Yeah ... I got it. (Can't answer my own question yet ... LOL)

Used the "object sender" in the click event to gain access to the content property of the clicked Hyperlink button.

Thanks for looking anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I did the same, but used the Tag property to hold the id.

```
  <HyperlinkButton Content="{Binding name}" Tag="{Binding id}" Click="EditApplication" />



        void EditApplication(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            HyperlinkButton hb = (HyperlinkButton) sender;
            Edit(hb.Tag); 
        }
```